# How can I copy a directories contents alone?

Tags: linux, cp

I want to copy the contents of `~/old contents to ~/new` without the `~/old` directory itself

However when I do

```
cd ~/new
cp ../old ~/new
```

or

```
cd ~
cp -vr ~/old ~/new
```

or

```
cp -vr ~/old/ ~/new/
```

the `/old` directory itself also gets copied but I just want its contents (including its own subdirectories), not the `old` directory itself 'inside' `new`

Comment: shell scripting is programming, just as much as say, javascript is. However, you'll probably get a better answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
cp ~/old/* ~/new
```

sorry can't test this now, but you want to copy the contents to the new directory, and I want to fill up the answer with the minimum 30 characters :)

Comment: Yes this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$ cd ~/old
$ cp -r * ../new
```